# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when displaying CollapsingToolbarLayout in my android app?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Am having trouble displaying `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my android application. Would somebody please tell me where am going wrong... After running the application, I got this log

```
adroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:378)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:408)
at com.android.epepea.epepea.GPS.dynamicToolBarColor(GPS.java:108)
at com.android.epepea.epepea.GPS.onCreate(GPS.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity that am using to display the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` looks like this:

```
package com.android.epepea.epepea;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GPS extends AppCompatActivity {
    private UserData userData;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    private TextView userName;
    private TextView userEmail;

    private ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

    private ImageView header;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.login_recycler);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);


        // native objects;
        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        userEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_email);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        adapter = new LoginUserAdpter(this, items, getSupportFragmentManager(), drawerLayout, linearLayout);


        setUpRecyclerView();
        // classes
        userData = new UserData(this);
        String userNameSet = userData.getFirstName() + " " + userData.getSecondName();
        userName.setText(userNameSet);
        userEmail.setText(userData.getEmail());



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Epepea Gps");

         //header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_image);

        dynamicToolBarColor();
        toolBarTextAppearance();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Maps.class);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_oepn_maps);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }



    private void dynamicToolBarColor() {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_background_123);
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark));
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark));
            }
        });
    }

    private void toolBarTextAppearance() {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay);
    }


    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }

// Call this method from onDestroy()

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.drawer));
        System.gc();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        String[] menuText = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_text_array);
        int menuImages[] = {
                R.drawable.ic_stay_current_portrait_white_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_language_white_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_contact_mail_white_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_build_white_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_person_outline_white_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_receipt_white_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_white_24dp
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < menuText.length && i < menuImages.length; i++) {
            items.add(new Items(
                    menuText[i],
                    menuImages[i]
            ));
        }

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(linearLayout)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Confirm Close")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close app?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            exitApp();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .show();

        }
    }

    public void exitApp() {
        super.finish();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(linearLayout))
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
            else
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(linearLayout);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My Xml Layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.android.epepea.epepea.GPS">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_background_123"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_gps" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_oepn_maps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_white_36dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@color/system_color"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- some content comes here -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_background_nice_kitkat"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="Benson Karue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="bensonkarue30@gmail.com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="#e1e1e1" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/login_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Would appreciate too much if I get somebody to assist me. Regards.

Comment: I think this is because your Image. try to use smaller size Image

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_background_123);
```

you are decoding high resolution image. In order to manage that with a library you can use one of these:

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

or if you want to generate palette by picasso first read [this article](http://jakewharton.com/coercing-picasso-to-play-with-palette/)

[Picassopalette](http://florent37.github.io/PicassoPalette/)
is another library you can use to generate palette by picasso.

or you can use this code for glide:

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(your image path,id,...)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    Palette.Builder palette = Palette.from(resource);
                    palette.generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                         }
                   });
                }
            });
```